# How do you grab an image's geotag in android?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-camera, locationlistener, geotagging

I know every image already comes with a geotag, so instead of grabbing the location while the user is taking a picture (as I have already implemented that code), is there a way to grab the geotag directly? If you guys have example code or a link to where it is done, that would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: "I know every image already comes with a geotag" -- no, they do not. "as I have already implemented that code" -- then provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are taking the picture, as you may or may not have geotags in the first place. If you have a path to a JPEG image, you can use the `ExifInterface` class in the Android SDK to get the geo information. If you have a `Uri` to a JPEG image, you will need to use other code to get the EXIF headers, such as [this code I extracted from the AOSP](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/tree/master/cam2/src/main/java/com/android/mms).

Comment: @CommonsWare okay. Sounds good, thanks for the input sir.